# Creating and running a Go build for Mac only

Tags: bash, macos, shell, go

I am into a situation in which I have to run a Go build on macOS/OS X. The build will be generated from the Linux operating system, and that build I have to run on macOS/OS X.

I have tried to generate a cross-platform build for Mac using the below command and build is generated.

```
env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build
```

This generated a Go build but I move this build to Mac it shows .dms file extension.

Now I have two questions:

- Am I generating the right build for Mac?
- How do I run this? A DMS file on Mac?

Answer (score 27):

Since your binary will target OS X, you need to set `GOOS` to `darwin`, so your command will be:

```
env GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go build
```

Documentation on compiler environment variables is in *[Optional environment variables](https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment)*.

To run the binary on Mac, you need to make sure that binary is executable:

```
chmod +x path-to-binary
```

And then run it in [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)#Terminal):

```
path-to-binary
```